# Postman send multiple requests

Tags: postman

I've got a PATCH request that looks like this:
`{{host}}/api/invoice/12345678/withdraw`
host is a variable determining the environment.

For this request I need to add a unique authorization token.
[image: auth token]

The problem is I need to send dozens of such requests. Two things change for each request:

1. id of invoice (for this case is '12345678')
2. auth token (herebetoken1).

How can I automate it?

Comment: how are you generating auth token for each request ? you know the token before hand ?

Comment: Yes, it is added manually to DB

Comment: How are you accessing the value from db in postman

Comment: I've got all the values. Its a hashmap like so: {invoiceId: authToken}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Postman **Runner** for your problem. In Runner, you can send specified requests in specified iterations and delay with data (json or csv file).

For more info, I suggest you take a look at the links below.

- [Importing Data Files in Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/working-with-data-files/)
- [Using CSV and JSON Data Files](https://blog.postman.com/using-csv-and-json-files-in-the-postman-collection-runner/)

**Request:**
[image: Example Request]

**Runner:**
[image: runner]

**Data: (You can choose one of them)**

**Json Data: (data.json)**

[image: json data]

**csv Data: (data.csv)**

[image: csv]

**Preview Data in Runner:**

[image: preview]

**Result:**
[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

use the below pre-request script , and call replace id in url and auth in authorization with {{id}} and {{token}} variables . Use collection runner to execute it .

Replace the hashmap with what you requires

```
hashmap = {
    "1234": "authtoken1",
    "2222": "authtoken2"
}

pm.variables.get("count") === undefined ? pm.variables.set("count", 0) : null

let keyval = Object.entries(hashmap)
let count = pm.variables.get("count")
if (count < keyval.length) {
    pm.variables.set("id", keyval[pm.variables.get("count")][0])
    pm.variables.set("token", keyval[pm.variables.get("count")][1])
    pm.variables.set("count", ++count)
    keyval.length===count? null:postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName)
}
```

**Example collection:**

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/43deac65a6de60ac46b3 , click inport and import by link